# Can't find Windows 8.1 in store after KB 2871389 install and wsreset.exe

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I'm running Windows 8 on a brand new Dell Inspiron 15 inch nontouch.

I can't find Windows 8.1 update even after the recommended update install and running wsreset.exe.

I even ran the Windows 8.1 Assistant and it told me I can download Windows 8.1 and directed me to the Windows Store.

Edit: It only says Windows 8 under Edition in properties. Also, as I mentioned above, I have tried using the assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the upgrade assistant from the Microsoft website?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_DIS_ShopHP_FPP_Light

Answer (score 0):

OK I had the same issue and resolved it using the following steps

Go to the update history and find the KB2871389 update. Uninstall this update.

Run Search for updates again and it should pick this update up and install it.

Reboot laptop and you should now find that the store has the windows 8.1 update.